# Drupal 7 multilingual support

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multilingual

I have built a site in Drupal 7. Unaware of complications I used German and English throughout the built. Now I am trying to add multilingual support and see my default lang is English.

My question is, do I go back and change all text/alias/references to English German and then go on about adding the multilingual support, or just add the support and switcher and clean up afterward?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you use single-site configuration and manually created English and German nodes. And now you want to make site true multilingual.
In this case you should do following steps:

1. Enable multilingual support - enable modules: Locale, Content translation, Internationalization, Multilingual content
2. Add Languages
3. Change configuration of each content type that you want to translate (/admin/structure/types). Set Publish Options -> Multilingual support -> "Enabled, with translation"
4. Go through all your nodes and set valid Language for each one
5. Link original nodes with translations

   - Open each original node and find Translation tab
   - Translation tab contains panel "Select translations for...". You can link your translations to the original node here
6. Now you can enable Language switcher block and test your site